# Remove Wubi boot menu entry

Tags: boot, wubi

I had a Windows laptop and I installed Ubuntu 17.10 with wubi. Soon after, I needed to clean up Windows and I restored it via its own restore function, which deletes all data and preferences and reverts Windows to factory version. I didn't uninstall Wubi before doing that.

When booting, my computer didn't show me the option to boot into Ubuntu unless I manually entered the boot menu. Now, if I enter the boot menu, I still see the Ubuntu option from before the restore, but if I choose it doesn't find Ubuntu.

I needed Ubuntu again so I reinstalled it again via Wubi, (Wubi didn't offer me an option to uninstall the previous version) and now in the boot menu I have two "Ubuntu" entries.

How do I remove the old one? The old install of wubi is not there any more so I suppose it's just a matter of editing the options of the boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem:

From [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1050238/how-do-edit-the-contents-of-my-bios-boot-list), I used [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) to delete the menu entry that was not needed. This solved the issue.